# Does VLC for Android show the true bitrate of m4a files?

Tags: vlc

I downloaded an audio file in m4a format, which in all other apps (eg. BlackPlayer, Phonograph) shows a bitrate of 32 kbps. But VLC shows 1.4 mbps!! What is going on? Does VLC somehow decompress the M4A music and then shows the original bitrate?
As you can see in this screenshot, the file size is barely 992.4 kb, so how can it have a bitrate of 1.4 mbps?? (https://i.stack.imgur.com/fe02b.png)